What is the difference between ASP.NET WebHooks and Signal-R
What is the difference between the ASP.NET WebHooks and Signal-R? What are the advantages or disadvantages? What are the use cases for each technology?
I don't know the difference. i think both are the same !! and if there is any documentation to how to use webhooks ?

Those 2 technologies may seem similar, but they follow different purposes and are built differently.
Webhooks are basically a notification model that pushes events to other web services, usually externally. Webhooks are not necessarily real-time and operate in a single direction, meaning external applications subscribe to events from webhooks.
Meanwhile SignalR is a framework that allows to build real-time applications/services. Its difference from webhooks is that SignalR is actually a framework that supports various protocols, while webhooks are just a model of notification. Additionally, SignalR allows to communicate bi-directionally in contrast to pub/sub model.
